# libsvm - training data format for multiclass classification

Tags: opencv, classification, svm, libsvm

I did **prohibitory** traffic sign detection in OpenCV. Now, I want to do recognize them. For example, I need to distinguish between speed limit 20km/h and speed limit 30km/h when I detect them.

In order to save time, I decided to use pre-calculated features of German Traffic Sign Recognition (GTSRB) benchmark for classification training. ***In GTSRB there are 12 different prohibitory traffic sign classes, the rest of them are other classes***. For each training image, HOG, HAAR, and Hue histogram features are calculated and stored in different folders. I am using pre-calculated HOG features that has vector dimension of 1568 for each training image.

I have two ideas about preparing the training data matrix in LIBSVM format. I am not sure which format I should use for multiclass classification. I already wrote C++ program to convert the features in different files to LIBSVM format.

**Question 1**: Which of the following ideas is right way to do recognize prohibitory traffic signs?

**Question 2**: I need to visualize the recognized signs in real time. However, the examples in libsvm only shows the accuracy level. Is libsvm the right choice or should I create training data matrix in OpenCV while running my traffic sign detection program?

**IDEA 1: Assign +1 label to all prohibitory classes and -1 to other classes**

```
 +1 1:0.32 2:0.27 3: 0.01 ... 1568:0.04 //class 1 - speed limit 20
 .                                      //features of training images
 .                                      
 .                                     
 +1 1:0.44 2:0.12 3: 0.23 ... 1568:0.03 //class 2 - speed limit 30
 .                                      //features of training images
 .                       
 .               
 +1 1:0.32 2:0.27 3: 0.01 ... 1568:0.04 //class 12 - speed limit 80
 .                                      //features of training images
 . 
 .
 -1 1:0.32 2:0.27 3: 0.01 ... 1568:0.04 //other classes
 .                                     //features of training images
 . 
 .
```

**IDEA 2: Assign 12 different labels to each prohibitory class and -1 for all other classes.**

```
 +1 1:0.32 2:0.27 3: 0.01 ... 1568:0.04 //class 1 - speed limit 20
 .                                      //features of training images
 .                                      
 .                                     
 +2 1:0.44 2:0.12 3: 0.23 ... 1568:0.03 //class 2 - speed limit 30
 .                                      //features of training images
 .                       
 .               
 +12 1:0.32 2:0.27 3: 0.01 ... 1568:0.04 //class 12 - speed limit 80
 .                                       //features of training images
 . 
 .
 -1  1:0.65 2:0.72 3: 0.12 ... 1568:0.12 //all other classes 
 .                                       //features of training images
 . 
 .
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

**Q1** If it works, you should prefer idea 1. The reason is that it will involve much less training. If there are N classes, for multiclass classification LIBSVM internally trains N(N-1)/2 classifiers.

So if N=2 (idea 1) LIBSVM trains one classifier. But if N=13 (idea 2), LIBSVM trains 78 classifiers.
That doesn't mean it will be 78 times slower, though, it gets complicated.

**Q2** This can't be answered as it depends on things you haven't mentioned, and is somewhat a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will compare two approaches and see the difference.